# Why does this code fail to compile?

Tags: c++, floating-point, valarray

I know it's a pretty general title, but I have some code and it strikes me as weird that it cant compile.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d4a5f2c0f0254e0) is a demo of the issue. If you change `scalar_t` from `double` to `float` the code compiles fine. Why cant float be promoted to double here? In fact, if you change the constants to `double`s (`1.0`) or `int`s (`1`) they also cant be promoted. Isn't this the kind of thing that should just work?

Full code sample:

```
#include <valarray>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T sigmoid(const T &in)
{
    return 1.f / (1.f + std::exp(-in));
}

template<typename T>
T logit(const T &in)
{
    return std::log(in / (1.f - in));
}

using scalar_t = double;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::valarray<scalar_t> f = { 0.1f, 0.3f, 0.5f, 0.9f };

    scalar_t alpha = 0.5f;
    scalar_t beta = -1.f;

    auto lC = logit(f);    
    std::valarray<scalar_t> skC = alpha * lC + beta;
    auto sC = sigmoid(skC);

    std::copy(std::begin(sC), std::end(sC), std::ostream_iterator<scalar_t>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    scalar_t num = 0.7f;
    auto lS = logit(num);
    auto sS = sigmoid(alpha * lS + beta);

    std::cout << sS << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Promotion is not the problem. `valarray`'s `operator-` deduces the same type for both the left hand side (`T const&`) and right hand side (`valarray<T> const&`). It's conflicted because it gets both `float` and `double` for the same template argument. You should be able to fix it by doing  `1.0`.

Comment: "Why cant float be promoted to double here?" What specific point in your code are you referring to as "here"? What promotion are you talking about?

Comment: @0x499602D2 You're right but why shouldnt an implicit conversion happen here? I cant really fix it by doing 1.0 because I don't have prior knowledge of `scalar_t` (or assume I don't for this discussion)

Comment: @AnT At the point of compiler failure, which I probably should have said in the post is at the return from `logit` (you can see that in the coliru sample)

Comment: @Max Ehrlich: In deduction context it is too early to think about any "promotions". E.g. `std::max(1.0, 1.0f)` does not compile for the same reason, even though the types are convertible. It is not the conversion that fails, it is the deductin that fails.

Comment: @MaxEhrlich Deduction of the template argument must happen before any conversion occurs. `T` is getting different types (`float` and `double`) compilation halts there. You can probably fix it by doing `T(1.0)` if you don't know the type of `T`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Well that would work except that T could be a `scalar_t` or a `valarray<scalar_t>` in which case `T(1.0)` wouldnt work

Comment: @AnT Right, the mechanism makes sense to me, I am just wondering how I can use a constant in a template function like this. All the operators work out to allow this to work fine on a scalar type or a `valarray` it's just that if I have a constant in my expression, then what type can it be?

Comment: @MaxEhrlich Instead of editing the question, it would have been better to put the solution in an answer (nothing wrong with answering your own question)

Comment: @njuffa True it would have been cleaner but what I have doesn't really answer the asked question (why doesnt this compile as written) which NathOliver did well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `operator -` you are using is defined as

```
template <class T> std::valarray<T> operator- (const T& val, const std::valarray<T>& rhs);
```

This meas that it expects `val` to be the same type as the elements in the `valarray`.  Since you are using a `float` when template argument deduction happens it sees that `val` is a `float` but `rhs` has a element type of `double`.  since these types do not match the deduction fails and you get a compiler error.  Remember no conversions happen during template argument deduction.

Comment: "no conversions happen during template argument deduction" I think is the problem. So the obvious next question is, how can I fix it assuming I don't know about `scalar_t`? Also why shouldnt implicit conversions be allowed in this scenario?

Comment: @MaxEhrlich Simplest would be to convert the literals to `scalar_t`'s.  If the function will only be used for standard types you could always you the `value_type` member and cast the literals to that type.

Comment: That would solve it for this sample, but assume I have no prior knowledge of `scalar_t` and no knowledge of the type of `T` at all (as you can see I've used it in the same as a `scalar_t` as well as a `valarray<scalar_t>` both of which should work fine except for the missing implicit conversion)

Comment: @MaxEhrlich Really I would just add a overload for a `std::valarray`.  Do the special case in there and then you have the main template for everything else.

Comment: That's how I handled it in the production code, but for my own purposes I am wondering if we can't do better. It seems maybe not

Comment: @MaxEhrlich I do not see one.  If you find one or someone else gives you a way I would love to hear about it.

Comment: Well you're not going to flippin believe this but I actually did it I think. I was looking at `sigmoid` and realized that it doesnt have the same issue because by the time it gets to the constants it is a template expression which works for whatever reason. The solution is to add a unary + before doing anything with the valarray http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c8c11cc06cb706f

Comment: @MaxEhrlich I believe that is because unary + states *The function can be implemented with the return type different from std::valarray. In this case[...]*  So the type you have is no longer a `valarray` but something like it and that can be used with the `float`.

Comment: Exactly. It's using the expression templates which seems to provide a valid overload for the double or float (and I suspect int) case

Comment: @MaxEhrlich I would remove the solution you found from your question and put it up as an answer since it shows how you could overcome the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This spawned a pretty interesting discussion about how to use constants in these type agnostic templates. Surprisingly there seems to be an answer. Examining the `sigmoid` function, we see that it also uses `float` constants with a `valarray<double>` but doesnt exhibit a compiler error. This is because, the `std::exp(-in)` line converts the `valarray<double>` to an expression template used the the standard library to optimize the computation, and for whatever reason it doesn't care about `float` or `double` (e.g. they provide the overload). So the solution I came up with was to add a unary + operator to the `logit` function which does absolutely nothing except convert the `valarray<double>` to an expression template which can work with the `float` constant.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c8c11cc06cb706f) is the update code sample

and the new `logit` function looks like this

```
template<typename T>
T logit(const T &in)
{
    return std::log(in / (1.f - (+in)));
}
```

Note the unary + operator `(+in)`

Also note that NathanOliver's accepted solution answers the question as asked